# Requests 'Connection refused' when run on a local machine but works on google colab

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, google-colaboratory, urllib3

It may may be a very simple question but I'm stuck here.
I tried to scrap a very well known website using the following command:

```
search_url = 'http://www.p***hub.com/'
response = requests.get(search_url)
```

But I getting the following response when I try to run it localy on my computer:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.p***hub.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f61969838d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

However, it does work when the same script is run on google colab. So I tried to use a proxy with requests (several different ones), but I still get the same error.

If someone knows how to solve this, I would really appreciate that.

Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: Try to add `User-Agent` header

Comment: I tried using headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'} but it still doesn't work :/